The orders of the exceptional Weyl groups
Who first calculated the orders of the Weyl groups $E_6$, $E_7$, $E_8$, $F_4$, and $G_2$? How were these orders calculated?

I can't do it now as I'm on my phone, but did you check whether there are historical notes to Bourbaki's volume on Lie groups? Did you search for the number 696729600 in Cartan's papers? Did you check whether Kane's book on reflection groups includes an original citation?

Surely the order of W(G_2) was known long before Lie . . . I think even the E_8 lattice was discovered before its connection with Lie theory.  So probably the Weyl-group orders were known almost as soon as those lattices appeared in the theory of Lie groups and algebras.

I suspect it was Killing in the 1880s or 1890s, but I don't have a reference for you.

The orders of the Weyl groups of root systems of type $E_6$, $E_7$, $E_8$ seem to appear in a 1894 Comptes Rendus paper [1] of Cartan, pp. 641-642. The paper [2] has the details and the orders appear on p.39, p. 48, p. 51.
[1] Cartan, É. Sur la réduction de la structure d’un groupe à sa forme canonique.  C. R. 119, 639-642 (1894). zbMATH http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k30752.f639
[2] Cartan, É. Sur la réduction à sa forme canonique de la structure d’un groupe de transformations fini et continu. American J. 18, 1-61 (1896).  zbMATH https://doi.org/10.2307/2369787

Bravo! One might add that, per Bourbaki’s notes mentioned by Gro-Tsen (2002, p. 251), it is also Cartan who first clarified in (1925, p. 366) that our Weyl group $(\mathscr G')$ may differ from the “characteristic equation Galois group” $(\mathscr G)$ that [2] emphasized (and already related to known groups whose orders are in Jordan): the former is naturally normal in the latter with (for $\mathfrak g$ simple) index 1, 2 or 6.

@FrancoisZiegler, very interesting! Thanks for adding that note! :)

@paulgarrett Thanks, you’re very kind. Extra tidbit: Borel (2001, p. 153) writes: “Chevalley asserts in (1952) that the terminology “Weyl group” had been proposed by him. I presume this was orally, because, as far as I know, this is indeed its first occurrence in print.” While that is not quite true (one finds “der Weylschen Gruppe” in two 1927 reviews by Freudenthal), it still further ambiguates the question — or makes it “ahistorical” — before that year.

My guess: these orders were first computed by Coxeter in his thesis

The polytopes with regular-prismatic vertex figures, Philos. Transactions (A) 229, 329–425 (1930). ZBL56.1119.03,

$E_l$ as $(\mathrm{PA})_l$ on p. 384, $F_4$ as $\{3,4,3\}$ and $G_2$ as $\{6\}$ on p. 349. But one might say that he only identified them as Weyl groups in the concluding §3.6 (pp. 186–210) of the 1935 Weyl seminar notes, The structure and representation of continuous groups: see pp. 201 and 208–209 for the orders, and p. 185 for Weyl’s formula to compute them.
Note added: Coxeter’s later book Regular Polytopes devotes §11·9 to Weyl’s formula, and in historical section §11·x notes that the groups $[3,4,3]$ (of $F_4$), resp. $[3^{l-4,2,1}]$ (of $E_{l=6,7,8}$) were already, linearly represented and with orders, in Goursat (1889, pp. 86–88), resp. Burnside (1911, pp. 299–308) with notation $\{G_l,T\}$. Moreover Burnside identified

(pp. 285, 302) his $\{G_6,T\}$ as the group of 27 lines on a cubic surface. That’s an implicit reference to Jordan (1870, nº441) or (1869, p. 658) where this group is defined and its order computed as 27·10·8·24 = 72·6! or indeed 51840.

(pp. 285, 305) his $\{G_7,T\}$ modulo a normal $\mathbf Z_2$ as the group of 28 bitangents to a plane quartic. That’s an implicit reference to Weber (1883, p. 493) where this group is defined and its order computed as 4·9! or indeed one half of 2903040.

(pp. 285, 308) his $\{G_8,T\}$ modulo a normal $\mathbf Z_2$ as Jordan’s first hypoabelian group on eight symbols. That’s an explicit reference to (1870, nº262) or (1869, p. 657) where this group is defined and its order computed in two ways (where $\newcommand\P{\mathscr P}$ $\P_n := 2^{2n-1} + 2^{n-1}$), both of which evaluate to 96·10! or indeed one half of 696729600:
$$
\style{font-family:sans-serif}{\text{in 1870,}} \qquad
\omega_4 = 2^0(\P_1-1)2^2(\P_2-1)2^4(\P_3-1)2^6(\P_4-1);\\
\style{font-family:sans-serif}{\text{in 1869,}} \qquad
\mathrm O_4 = 2^1(2^2-1)2^3(2^4-1)2^5(2^6-1)2^7(2^8-1)/\P_4.
$$


This I think supports @NoamD.Elkies’ notion that these groups (and orders!) had long been known and ready to be identified — with the subtlety of Cartan and Weyl’s slightly different definitions ($\mathscr G$ vs. $\mathscr G'$) mentioned in my other comment. Thus Cartan in 1896 cited the exact same three above-italicized groups, on pp. 43, 50, 54 of @testaccount’s reference [2]; and his whole notation, terminology (e.g. roots that “meet”), and switch from $\mathrm G$ to $\mathrm G_1$ (our $\mathscr G$ and $\mathscr G'$) in the $E_6$ case (p. 39) were clearly informed by knowing Jordan’s group of 27 lines.
Second note added: I. Dolgachev’s great book Classical Algebraic Geometry: a modern view ends Chap. 8|9 with a very relevant historical note (earlier detailed in his (1983, §§1 & 7)):

The Weyl group $\mathrm W(E_6)$ as the Galois group of 27 lines was first studied by C. Jordan (1870). Together with the group of 28 bitangents of a plane quartic isomorphic to $\mathrm W(E_7)$, it is discussed in many classical text-books in algebra (e.g. Weber). S. Kantor (1895) realized the Weyl group $\mathrm W(E_n)$, $n \leqslant 8$, as a group of linear transformations preserving a quadratic form of signature $(1, n)$ and a linear form. A. Coble (1916) was the first who showed that the group is generated by the permutations group and one additional involution. So we should credit him with the discovery of the Weyl groups as reflection groups. Apparently independently of Coble, this fact was rediscovered by P. Du Val (1936). We refer to Bourbaki for the history of Weyl groups, reflection groups and root systems. Note that the realization of the Weyl group as a reflection group in the theory of Lie algebras was obtained by H. Weyl in 1928, ten years later after Coble’s work.

Sure enough, looking these up finds the orders of $\mathrm W(E_6)$ and $\mathrm W(E_7)$ in Kantor (1895, p. 22), and those of $\mathrm W(E_6)$, $\mathrm W(E_7)/\mathbf Z_2$, $\mathrm W(E_8)/\mathbf Z_2$ in Coble (1916, p. 356). (On the other hand, it seems to me that what is attributed here to Coble was done by Burnside 5 years earlier...?)

I suppose 51840 comes from the order of $O_6^{-}(2)$, which is a group that Jordan studied for other reasons. And $W(E_6) \cong O_6^{-}(2)$.

For the record, @testaccount’s comment was on an earlier version, where for $E_6$ I followed a path of explicit citations from Burnside (p. 302) to Burkhardt (1892, pp. 317–326) to Maschke (1889, title) to Witting (1887, p. 167) to Jordan (1869, p. 866) or (1870, nº499) where the formula $\Omega_2 = 3(3^2-1)3^3(3^4-1)$ also evaluates to 51840.

... and I was confused by this path, and still am, because Coxeter (1940, p. 470) or Frame (1951, front page) say that these authors are talking about a nonisomorphic group of (coincidentally) the same order.

@FrancoisZiegler: The paper of Frame you mention cites a 1869 paper of Jordan, where the group that Jordan considers is $\operatorname{Sp}(4,3)$. Meanwhile the Weyl group of $E_6$ is isomorphic to $O_6^{-}(2)$. These groups have the same order but are not isomorphic. Both have the simple group $\operatorname{PSp}(4,3) \cong \Omega_6^{-}(2)$ as a composition factor, one has it as a quotient and the other one as a subgroup.

@MikkoKorhonen Thanks. That 1869 note’s p. 866 is linked above, and the mixup seems to be right there, p. 868: “Z has the remarkable particularity to have the same group as the equation which determines the twenty-seven lines on a cubic surface”. Then repeated in his book, nº504 (“X a donc le même groupe”), Maschke (loc. cit., p. 319) (“isomorph”), Burkhardt (1891, p. 187) (“dass sie isomorph ist”), Burnside (loc. cit., p. 302) (“It is simply isomorphic”) and unless I’m mistaken, even today Lê (2015, pp. 152–155 & 333–367).

Following up on Dave Benson's comment, the MacTutor Killing entry explains that, in correspondence with Engel, Killing found $G_2$ in May of 1887 and the others that fall.  This is reported (including the dimensions, summarized on the last page) in the second part of a Mathematische Annalen series which carries a submission date of 2 February 1888.
Wilhelm Killing. Die Zusammensetzung der stetigen endlichen Transformationsgruppen, Zweiter Theil.  Math. Ann. 33 (1889) 1–48.
Available at The European Digital Mathematics Library, reviewed by Engel in https://zbmath.org/20.0368.03.

As Francois points out, this is not the intended parameter.

Part of what Cartan was doing in the nineties was giving rigour and detail to Killing's pioneering work. And I don't at all mean by that, to detract from the tremendous job he did of laying the groundwork for what followed.

Killing has the Lie algebra dimensions, not the Weyl group orders.

Thanks @FrancoisZiegler.  As some support for your answer, the first Google Scholar reference for the numbers 2903040 and 696729600 is Coxeter.

@DaveBenson: Indeed. A nice book that discusses this part of the history in more detail: T. Hawkins, Emergence of the theory of Lie groups. An essay in the history of mathematics 1869-1926. Sources and Studies in the History of Mathematics and Physical Sciences. Springer-Verlag, New York, 2000. xiv+564 pp https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-1202-7
